# How to use PowerShell to flatten a folder with duplicate file names?

Tags: powershell-cmdlet

There are many folders in a father folder and some files with the same name in these folders.

Like this:

folder/folder1/1.txt

folder/folder2/1.txt

folder/1.txt

How to "flatten" the father folder by PowerShell like this:

folder/folder1-1.txt

folder/folder2-1.txt

folder/1.txt

I use mouse and keyboard to rename the files one by one.